# What materials are fossils made of?

Tags: paleontology, fossils

I was reading on fossilization and I came across petrifaction. Are fossils that take the shape (have the shape) of the original organism made of only stone or iron? Can there be a fossil made of any other substance?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrifaction) mentions stone/iron fossils:

> The minerals commonly involved in replacement are calcite, silica, pyrite, and hematite.

Are all minerals involved in "replacement" a stone/iron material, or are other materials ever involved in this process?

Thank you.

Comment: what does your research show about how fossils form? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil

Comment: "stone" covers literally every naturally occurring solid on earth not made by an organism and quite a few that are. if they were not made of stone what would they be made of?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework questions are off topic without showing some prior research.

Comment: This is not a homework question. I am just trying to understand some aspects of fossils to see a link between this and something else. I understood some basics of fossils from YouTube though the information I see is very confusing regarding details. I do not have education on the subject.

Comment: Also note that I have read the article @ wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrifaction and I have watched YouTube videos which point into the direction of stone/iron fossils. In the wiki article, I was trying to understand what the author(s) meant when he said "The minerals commonly involved in replacement are calcite, silica, pyrite, and hematite." I missed the part about hematite being of iron. When the author said 'commonly involved' I wanted to know if fossils can also only be of stone/iron in the uncommon sense (other materials).

Answer (score 2):

Fossilization can occur using literally any mineral that is water soluble, which nearly all of them are. The problem you are running into is "fossil" covers a huge range of things, from insects in amber to shell casts, to permineralized dinosaur bones, the chemistry of the processes therefore also cover a huge range of things and will require quite a solid understanding of geochemistry. Worse, the early stages of fossilization are not well understood. By its nature, figuring out what is and is not in the process of becoming a fossil is difficult, so there are several competing ideas and all of them might well be true.

A few quick definitions.

Stone is any solid composed of nonliving material with a fairly well defined chemical composition, stone is one of the broadest definitions in science.

There is a free textbook on paleontology online, that should be a good spot to get started.

*[Introduction to Paleobiology and the Fossil Record](https://www.a-centauri.com/archivio/geo/Paleontologia/Benton_Introduction%20to%20Paleobiology%20and%20the%20Fossil%20Record.pdf)*, Michael J Benton and David A. T. Harper, Wiley-Blackwell.